# Why does MySQL/Sequelize perform full select queries when a GraphQL query only requires certain fields of an object to be returned?

Tags: mysql, express, graphql, sequelize.js, typegraphql

I have a simple schema like this for a user in my application:

```
type Query {
  users: [User!]!
}

# The User ObjectType and Sequelize model.
type User implements UserI {
  id: ID!
  userName: String!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  email: String!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  deletedAt: DateTime!
}
```

And my `type-graphql` resolver implements this simple code to return a list of `users`:

```
@Resolver()
class UserResolver {
  @Query(() => [User])
  async users(): Promise<User[]> {
    return User.findAll();
  }
}
```

When I perform a query such as this:

```
{
  users {
    firstName
  }
}
```

I expected that the equivalent MySQL query would be something like this: `SELECT firstName FROM users`, but instead I can see that Sequelize logged the query as this:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `userName`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE (`User`.`deletedAt` IS NULL);
```

Now, while everything works (I can get all the users and their data on the client side) I was wondering if there are any performance hits on the server side if Sequelize performs full attribute selection? Is this due to Sequelize or simply due to how GraphQL resolves the model field's? Am I missing some options?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing some options?

You need to translate GraphQL query (request) into the proper SQL query. Just calling `findAll()` does not have any info about the request, so it correctly fetches full entity.

Basically, you need to parse the GraphQL Resolve Info into a more readable format (e.g. using https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-fields) and then build a `select` option for TypeORM (e.g. `.findAll({ select: ['id'] })`).